# Duplicate e-mails for recipient in distribution list and TO list

Tags: exchange-2010

I have recipients who get two copies of e-mails if:

1. His e-mail address is in the TO list **and**
2. He is a member of a distribution list that is also in the TO list.

Because of how a particular application works, this scenario sometimes happens.

How can Microsoft Exchange prevent this situation and send the e-mails only once to each recipient ?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about An active directory Distribution list (group), Outlook Distribution list, or some kind of 3rd party mail list software?

Comment: Are the distribution list and the user's email in different domains?

Comment: @Zoredache AD list

Comment: @Shane different (I suspected this might be the problem, but was unable to replicate the behavior in this scenario with a test DL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution list and user's e-mail have different domains. I just made them the same.

@Shane Madden - if you want credit for this answer, add it, and I'll mark it correct.